# Why are superclass The superclass is parameterized in JAVA

Tags: android, unit-testing

```
package com.android.example.spinner.test;

import com.android.example.spinner.SpinnerActivity;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class SpinnerActivityTest extends
  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SpinnerActivity> {



}
```

Comment: I don't think this constitutes as a question.

Answer (score 2):

This is because we are declaring that SpinnerActivityTest is a specific type of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 – one that deals in some way with SpinnerActivity objects.

As to how SpinnerActivity is significant to the TestCase class, well, you would have to look at the class concerned.